# CodeIgneter routing does not work as expected after updating to 3.x

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have finally migrated from a really old version of `CI` and had fixed all of the issues except one. There is one action that cannot be routed appropriately.

**routes.php**

```
$route['admin/calendar/show/(:any)'] = 'admin/cal/index/showweek/$1';
```

**calendar.php**

```
public function showweek($date = false, $sort = false, $template = false){
   ...code ommited...
}
```

It works alright if no paramenters or only `$date` is provided. If there are more than 2 parameters - request end in 404.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Make sure your controller file and class names have only first letter upper case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression to catch multiple segments at once.

```
$route['admin/calendar/show/(.+)'] = 'admin/cal/index/showweek/$1';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your route should look like this:

`$route['admin/calendar/show/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'admin/cal/index/showweek/$1/$2/$3';`